# Is it possible to break a tableofcontents and put it to a new page?

Tags: table-of-contents, split

Is it possible to break a \tableofcontents (maybe manually?) and put it to a new page? I added a picture to show the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add code with `\addtocontents`

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\chapter{B}
\end{document}
```

But it looks odd that it happens automatically in your example. Perhaps you added some code which prevents a break.

Comment: Many thanks - problem fixed by adding \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage} after \section{...}. Now it looks great!